# Variational problem equivalent to minimizing the energy functional

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Define the boundary value problem for Poisson's equation as:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-\Delta u=f & \text { in } \Omega \\
u=g & \text { on } \Gamma
\end{array},\right.
$$
for given $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g: \Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\Gamma=\partial \Omega$.

Now we define Dirichlet's energy as:
$$
I: \mathrm{C}^{1}(\bar{\Omega}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad I(v):=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^{2} d x-\int_{\Omega} f v d x \quad v \in \mathrm{C}^{1}(\bar{\Omega}),
$$
our class of admissible functions is this one
$$
\mathcal{K}:=\left\{v \in \mathrm{C}^{2}(\Omega): v=g \text { on } \Gamma\right\}
$$

Then I know this theorem holds:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded open set with
> $\Gamma=\partial \Omega$ of class $\mathrm{C}^{1}$ and let $f \in
>  \mathrm{C}^{0}(\bar{\Omega})$ and $g \in \mathrm{C}^{0}(\Gamma)$.
> Assume $u \in \mathcal{K}$ solves the boundary value problem above.
> Then $$ I(u)=\min _{v \in \mathcal{K}} I(v) . $$ Viceversa, if $u \in
>  \mathcal{K}$ satisfies this minimization problem, then $u$ solves the
> boundary-value problem.

But now I found this counterexample by Hadamard:

> Let $\mathbb{D}=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:|x|<1\right\}$, and let
> $u: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given in polar coordinates
> by $$ u(r, \theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-2} r^{n !} \sin (n !
>  \theta) $$ It is easy to check that each term of the series is
> harmonic, and the series converges absolutely uniformly in
> $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Hence $u$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$ and
> continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. On the other hand, we have $$
>  E(u)=\int_{\mathbb{D}}|\nabla u|^{2} \geq \int_{0}^{2 \pi}
>  \int_{0}^{\rho}\left|\partial_{r} u(r, \theta)\right|^{2} r
>  \mathrm{~d} r \mathrm{~d} \theta=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi n !}{2
>  n^{4}} \rho^{2 n !} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{\pi n !}{2 n^{4}}
>  \rho^{2 n !}, $$ for any $\rho<1$ and any integer $m$. This implies
> that $E(u)=\infty$. To conclude, there exists a Dirichlet datum $g \in
>  C(\partial \mathbb{D})$ for which the Dirichlet problem is perfectly
> solvable, but the solution cannot be obtained by minimizing the
> Dirichlet energy. There is no full equivalence between the Dirichlet
> problem and the minimization problem.

How is the theorem ruling out the counterexample?

Comment: Why do you think the theorem is true? Do you have a reference, or did you come up with the proof yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem is "almost" true, but stated as it is stated it is missing a technical condition (which is actually the one the counterexample is exploiting).

Let me state your theorem correctly:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded open set with
> $\Gamma=\partial \Omega$ of class $\mathrm{C}^{1}$ and let $f \in
>  \mathrm{C}^{0}(\bar{\Omega})$ and $g \in \mathrm{C}^{0}(\Gamma)$.
> Assume $u \in \mathcal{K}$ solves the boundary value problem

***and assume also there exists at least one function in $\mathcal{K}$ making the Dirichlet's integral finite.***

> Then $$ I(u)=\min _{v \in \mathcal{K}} I(v) . $$ Viceversa, if $u \in
>  \mathcal{K}$ satisfies this minimization problem, then $u$ solves the
> boundary-value problem.

Indeed notice that in your counterexample, all functions in $\mathcal{K}$, that is all functions that satisfy your "Dirichlet datum" $g \in \mathcal{C}(\partial \mathbb{D}$) have infinite Dirichlet energy by the computation above when you let $\rho = 1$ (that is, on the boundary of your domain).

The moral is the following: this is a nice example that technical conditions are not important as far as "main ideas" are concerned, but are important otherwise you may construct counterexamples that (in general) falsify your theorem.